# Desktop Client Recomendation

Tags: client

can you recommend me any desktop clients ? So far I have tried bitcoin-core, Electrum and MultiBit. I liked Bitcoin Core, but as the blocks increase, it becomes extremely heavy. In my computer, it takes more than 10 minutes just to start, and while it is syncing I can't do anything else without freezing my computer, MultiBit uses the file from a server, so it syncs very fast, but the wallet seems to be incompatible with the wallet.dat and it doesn't seem to allow importing the private key, it only allows importing wallets generated by itself. Electrum is fast, doesn't freeze anything, it allows to import private keys, but it is taking way too long to sync, so i think it is downloading the blockchain...

So, I would like a wallet with these characteristics:

- Allows to import/export wallet.dat file (or private key) (like Electrum and Bitcoin Core)
- Don't need to download the whole block (Like MultiBit)
- Runs on Linux

thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

Electrum does not download the whole blockchain. I would recommend giving it another try as it should be pretty much as fast as any other app. One thing you could try is switching the validation server. This would possibly increase the speed at which you are able to sync up.

About electrum validation:
"This wallet uses SPV and random servers from a list. This means little trust in third parties is required when verifying payments. However, it is not as secure as a full node like Bitcoin Core."

Information above taken from: https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

The above resource should help you pick another wallet besides electrum if you choose to do so.

Comment: From that link, the only wallets that fulfill my requests is electrum, and it should not be taking this long, perhaps is some error happening specifically with me, should i open a new question?

Comment: I would try switching the validation servers around. It is possible you have a poor connection to the default server. Here is a list of the servers: http://electrum.qc.to/ Look for one with low MS and try that.

Comment: i tryed switching server, closing and openning electrum again, sometimes one of my two wallets get synced, sometimes neither gets synced and never both get synced, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Recommend Bither Wallet[image]

User Manual：https://github.com/bither/bither-doc/blob/gh-pages/manual-English.md

Bither Wallet can

- Allows to import/export private key(QR code or plaintext)
- Don't need to download the whole block
- Runs on Linux/Windows/OS X/Android/iOS

Comment: Hey, when recommending software, please explain why your recommendation works best for the asker.